# when checking whether or not $x$ is prime, why should I try divisors less than or equal to $\sqrt{x}$ only?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If I want to check whether a number $x$ is prime or not, I may do the following:

```
let isPrime be true
let i = 3; till i * i <= x
    if x is divisible by i
        set isPrime to false
        break
    increase i by 2
if isPrime, then x is prime
else, x is not prime
```

why exactly should I just keep trying until $i \times i$ becomes greater than or equal to $x$?

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Ross Millikan has correctly answered your question, but just as side note: while this primality test is the easiest one to understand, there are others that are far more efficient.  The most common among these is the Miller-Rabin test: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every divisor $d$ of $x$ matches up with the quotient $\frac xd$.  One of the two is less than or equal to the square root of $x$.  If you check up to $\sqrt x$ you will find one of the two.

Comment: Why must one of them be less than or equal to the square root of x? I know this is true but I just want to know how concluded it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @KareemMesbah:  If $d \gt \sqrt x$ and $\frac xd \gt \sqrt x$, then $d\cdot \frac xd \gt \sqrt x \cdot \sqrt x =x$

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot! :)